# After Update Andoid 5.0.2 - tablet not syncing

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sync, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 (Model SM-T530NU). It was updated to the new Android 5.0.2 and now nothing is syncing. Games, Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, etc. are not syncing. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-adding those accounts?  Can you use the browser?

Answer (score 0):

It maybe possible that auto sync is off.

Follow these steps:

1. Tap Settings.
2. Select the Connections tab.
3. Tap Data usage.
4. Tap Menu, then select the Auto sync data check box.
5. Review the pop-up message, then tap OK.